# Mean value through average in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create mean value using the AVERAGE function in google spreadsheets. However, I've got to program my way out of including/excluding specific cells to include in data range for my function.

My data looks like this:

```
                    Q1         Q2

Town 1             1            4

Town 2              2            5

Town 1              3            4
```

In another sheet I've got to put the mean for the values into a cell, but only for the answers that entail "Town 1" so I have to exclude "Town 2" from my function. I cannot use the manual data-filtering, as it has to be analysed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work properly:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(Sheet1!B:C,Sheet1!A:A="City 1"))
```